# Failing to retrieve the third td nodes in an html list

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the text "Very Good Country views" and "Good" using HTMLAgilityPack.

```html
<div class="property-details-section">
<h5><span id="content_lblFurtherDetails">Further Details</span></h5>
    <ul id="features">                   
        <li style="display:block;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 15px;">
                        <img src="../images/bullet.png" alt="bullet" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 185px;">Views</td>
                    <td style="width: 300px;">Very Good Country views</td>
                      </tr>
             </table>
         </li>
      </ul>


       <li style="display:block;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
               <tr>
                  <td style="width: 15px;">
                      <img src="../images/bullet.png" alt="bullet" />
                  </td>
                  <td style="width: 185px;">Finish</td>
                  <td style="width: 300px;">Good</td>
                <tr>
            </table>

         </li>

   </div>
```

I have tried the following for "Very Good Country views" with no success:

```
HtmlNode text =
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@id='features']/li/table/tr/td[3]");
```

Comment: Nothing at all. Apart from that nullreferenceexception will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the text "Very Good Country views" and "Good"

You have to select 2 elements, so you should use *SelectNodes* instead of *SelectSingleNode*, if you want get the result at once.

```
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@id='features']/li/*//td[last()]")
                .Select(td => td.InnerText)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem about your `XPath` is that you should add brackets around the expression:

```
var text = doc.DocumentNode
     .SelectSingleNode("(//ul[@id='features']/li/table/tr/td)[3]");
```

You can also try using `LINQ`:

```
var td = doc.Descendants("ul")
        .First(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id","") == "features")
        .Descendants("td")
        .Skip(2)
        .First();

var text = td.InnerText;
```